# Why does it seem not OK to using "extern int a" in global scope?

Tags: c++, header, extern

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"
int a = 999;
int main() {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    printa();

    return 0;
}
```

**test.h**

```
#include <iostream>
extern const int a;
void printa(void) {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

When compiled and running, it works fine

But when I changed main.cpp to

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"
extern int a = 999; //here is the change, I have added extern
int main() {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    printa();

    return 0;
}
```

Works good but a warning shows up.

> warning: a initialized and declared

What is wrong?  **Why does it seem not OK to using "extern int a" in global scope ?**

Comment: constness of `extern const int a;` and `int a = 999;` differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it seem not OK to using "extern int a" in global scope ?

Actually it is *"OK"*. In your header, your variable is declared `extern` in the global scope and everything is fine with it.

1. You don't have to repeat the `extern` keyword when you want to initialize the variable. The variable is already known as `extern` at this point (in the .cpp) since the declaration has been already performed when including the header.
2. As ***@Jarod42*** mentioned in comment, your const declaration and non-const initialization mismatch.
3. If you initialize the `extern` variable when you declare it, then the `extern` becomes obsolete. The semantic of `extern` is "Ok, I defer the initialization somewhere else". Hence the warning.

For instance:

*.h*

```
extern int a;       // declaration, as extern (will be initialized somewhere else)
extern const int b; // example with const
```

*.cpp*

```
int a = 42;         // initialization
const int b = 4422; // initialization
```

Comment: The book I am reading tells me: If you want to use a defined  const variable  in another file, that const variable has to be explicitly set to extern. Why , in your example, const int b = 4422; doesn't have to be extern const int b = 4422; ?

Comment: @SleepingOnaGiant'sShoulder In my example it is `extern`, but in the declaration (in the header). `extern` means that you make a contract with the compiler and you guarantee that the variable will be initialized later on. In the translation unit where I want to initialize the variable, I do not need to use `extern` because the variable is already declared as extern, **I'm not redeclaring it** (which I should never do) but only initializing it.

Comment: @SleepingOnaGiant'sShoulder To be more clear, when you write `#include "test.h"`, you include `extern const int a;` as well. If you want to initialize it, you just have to add `const int a = 999;` as any other deferred global or static initialization.

Comment: Fareanor, thanks. Still don't understand the const part, just starting to learn C++

Comment: @SleepingOnaGiant'sShoulder The difference is that the const specifier indicates that the variable will never be modified (initialization does not count). If you did not declared the variable `extern` in the header, you would not be able to defer the initialization.

Answer (score 2):

> What is wrong?

Not wrong *per se* (hence a warning, not an error). But you are giving the compiler conflicting information:

`extern` tells the compiler, "this is defined elsewhere, let the linker handle it".

`= 999` tells the compiler, "this is (defined and) initialized right here to have the value `999`".

The compiler effectively ignores the `extern` at this point, and is warning you about the fact that information was conflicting.